# What does \newline do to the line justification?

Tags: line-breaking

I can't understand what `\newline` does to justify the line that it breaks. It's clear that `\linebreak` uses the justification of the paragraph and has the same effect as simply ending the paragraph (using `\par`, blank line, end of environment, etc), whereas `\newline` places the contents of the line slightly to the left w.r.t. the justification used. An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[left=7cm, right=7cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
 This is a centered paragraph that features text wrapping
 as well as \linebreak manual \linebreak breaks using \verb+\linebreak+ 

\bigskip
 This is a centered paragraph that features text wrapping
 as well as \newline manual \newline breaks using \verb+\newline+ 
\end{center}

\begin{flushright}
 This is a right-justified paragraph that features text wrapping
 as well as \linebreak manual \linebreak breaks using \verb+\linebreak+ 

\bigskip
 This is a right-justified paragraph that features text wrapping
 as well as \newline manual \newline breaks using \verb+\newline+ 
\end{flushright}

\begin{flushleft}
 This is a left-justified paragraph that features text wrapping
 as well as \linebreak manual \linebreak breaks using \verb+\linebreak+ 

\bigskip
 This is a left-justified paragraph that features text wrapping
 as well as \newline manual \newline breaks using \verb+\newline+ 
\end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The  definition of `\newline` boils down to `\hfil\break`.  The `center` environment essentially wraps every line in `\hfil <line>\hfil`. Similarly, `flushlight` adds `\hfil` in front of each line.

Thus a `\newline` inside a `center` environment is equivalent to

```
\hfil text \hfil\hfil\break
```

and inside `flushlight` to

```
\hfil text \hfil\break
```

obtaining the effect you describe.