# Difference between \newline, \linebreak, \break

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

What are the actual definitions of `\newline`, `\linebreak` and `\break` (and also `\par`)? Is the latter a TeX primitive? I can't find the relevant documentation anywhere regarding their precise function, other than general discussions, so perhaps someone can point me in that direction too.

This question originates from finding that `\newline` does not work as I had expected in a `\raggedleft` environment. I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/275829/274486) useful answer, which explains what is going on by declaring that `\newline` boils down to `\hfil\break`, which I can see is true upon experimentation but cannot find documentation for.

Answer (score 8):

#### TL;DR

***Simple strategy:*** never use `\newline` unless you have precise control of the environment.

***Simple strategy:*** never use `\break` in a LaTeX `document` environment.

#### Longer answer

This is not going to be simple, sorry.

The definition of `\newline` at begin document is

```
\@normalcr\relax
```

and we see

```
% latex.ltx, line 7444:
\protected\def\@normalcr{%
  \let \reserved@e \relax
  \let \reserved@f \relax
  \@ifstar{\let \reserved@e \vadjust \let \reserved@f \nobreak
             \@xnewline}%
  \@xnewline}

% latex.ltx, line 7454:
\def\@xnewline{\@ifnextchar[% ] bracket matching
                  \@newline
                 {\@gnewline\relax}}

% latex.ltx, line 7459:
\def\@gnewline #1{%
  \ifvmode
    \@nolnerr
  \else
    \unskip \reserved@e {\reserved@f#1}\nobreak \hfil \break
  \fi}
```

The reason for the complications is that the “standard” definition of `\newline` is the same as for `\\`, which can be followed by `*` and an optional argument.

So, no, `\newline` is not really `\hfil\break`.

However, `\newline` remains the same inside `flushleft`, `flushright` or `center`, whereas `\\` changes. Why doesn't `\newline` work inside `flushright` and `center`?

Let's consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{flushright}
X \newline Y
\end{flushright}

\begin{center}
X \newline Y
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first line inside `flushright` has `\hfil` glue at the left and also at the right of X, so the net effect is to center the X. Inside `center` it's even worse, because now there is again `\hfil` glue before X, but *two* globs of `\hfil` glue after it. Thus X gets placed with twice as much space after than before.

***Simple strategy:*** never use `\newline` unless you have precise control of the environment.

To the contrary, `\\` inside `flushright` and `center` gets a different definition so as to countermand the infinitely stretchable glues at either side.

What is `\break`? It's a macro inherited from plain TeX and used inside the kernel code for brevity.

***Simple strategy:*** never use `\break` in a LaTeX `document` environment. It's possible to use it in definitions (if you know what it does).

The preferred command is `\linebreak` for an important reason: `\linebreak` checks the mode it is found in, whereas `\break` doesn't. Both eventually issue `\penalty-10000` that forces a break: a line break if found in horizontal mode, a page break in vertical mode.

If you inadvertently issue `\break` between paragraphs, you get a page break. To the contrary, `\linebreak` between paragraphs will just tell you that

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
```

Comment: This looks excellent. It will take me a while to digest it, but will then upvote it.